# Can't find variables Connect , stack React native

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, react-navigation, connect

I was implementing redux in my application. and everything sets correctly. Program runs properly. But after sometime It was showing error.
Can't find variable connect.
I checked every files, app.js and navigations.. I do not forgot to call connect anywhere. I too tried to run simple codein App.js saying hello world. But it doesn't showed that too.
Sorry for long message.
[image: Error Image]
Here is the error message which I didnt get it.

Comment: please provide your codes for getting better result

Answer (score 0):

Try importing the connect function from react-redux.
 `import {connect} from 'react-redux'`.
 Install react-redux via npm too if it has not been installed already.

Comment: already installed. Ive imported connect on every page. It was working all ok. But suddenly after sometime it is showing me his message.